# Vue Vite + CosmicJS

Tags: vue.js, cosmicjs

I'm building a blog **SPA** website as a hobby, and trying to figure out what would be the best way to get the smallest latency to acquire posts from a database.

So far I've tried **Wordpress**, but its API at least at the very first initial request every time, with API cache enabled, ***takes about a second (800-1100ms) to load only a handful posts - 6 to be precise each with a picture and about 2-300 words, and this is only for testing.***

So I'm looking around for other possible solutions to make the request faster but ***stay free of charge*** and came across Cosmic JS.

I installed the `cosmicjs module`, but getting all sorts of errors as I try to initiate the requests, based on their documentation which looks like the following:

```
<script>
const Cosmic = require('cosmicjs')
const api = Cosmic()
// Set these values, found in Bucket > Settings after logging in at https://app.cosmicjs.com/login
const bucket = api.bucket({
  slug: "YOUR_BUCKET_SLUG",
  read_key: "YOUR_BUCKET_READ_KEY"
})
</script>
```

First, you can't use `require` in Vite, so I've changed
this

```
const Cosmic = require('cosmicjs')
```

to this

```
import Cosmic from "cosmicjs"
```

But I'm still getting error:

```
ReferenceError: process is not defined
    at node_modules/cosmicjs/dist/helpers/constants.js (cosmicjs.js?v=2a84de6d:1367:19)
    at __require2 (chunk-NKHIPFFU.js?v=2a84de6d:15:50)
    at node_modules/cosmicjs/dist/main.js (cosmicjs.js?v=2a84de6d:1387:21)
    at __require2 (chunk-NKHIPFFU.js?v=2a84de6d:15:50)
    at node_modules/cosmicjs/dist/index.js (cosmicjs.js?v=2a84de6d:3359:23)
    at __require2 (chunk-NKHIPFFU.js?v=2a84de6d:15:50)
    at cosmicjs.js?v=2a84de6d:3371:16ű
```

Can't figure out what to do next to even make this work, currently my code looks like this for the cosmic request part:

```
import Cosmic from "cosmicjs"

const api = Cosmic();


const bucket = api.bucket({
  slug: "NOT-GOING-TO-SHOW-SORRY-AND-THX",
  read_key: "NOT-GOING-TO-SHOW-SORRY-AND-THX",
});

const data = await bucket.objects
  .find({
    type: "posts", // Object Type slug
  })
  .props("title,slug,metadata") // response properties
  .limit(10); // number of Objects to be returned 

  console.log(data)
```

Any idea might be a good help, thanks in advance

Comment: I'm running this in the browser.

Comment: Sorry but your answers seem to indicate you didn't read my original post at all. I'm using Vue Vite, not cosmicjs. Vue Vite IS and always was a web development framework and a javascript based user interface, enablind developers to create eg. the now quite popular Single Page Applications, including Single Page websites. Within this environment is where I'm trying to use cosmicjs, which is basically a CMS database.

Comment: @Arber Ok I have to assume you are literally gaslighting at this point...
The cosmicjs is just a simple node module, and as you run either an 'npm run dev', or an 'npm run build' then 'npm run preview', the node.js is automatically ran. Which **should have been  obvious after I wrote in my original post, AND here too, that I'm running a Vue Vite framework**

Comment: @Arber Furthermore let me show you the **official documentation for the cosmicjs usage**
https://docs.cosmicjs.com/guides/vuejs
Check the code there and compare it to mine, quite similar isnt it? :)

Comment: Some advice from my own experience on this site: don't get involved in a comment war with anyone. If you find that someone's comment is non-constructive, either ignore the comment or flag it for moderator action, the type of flag depending on just how bad the comments are. Then (again) ignore the comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out:

So anyone trying to use **in `Vite` ANY node module that has `process` as a function in any part in that module, should do the following**

In your `vite.config.ts` or `vite.config.js` add the following

```
export default defineConfig({
  // ...
  define: {
    'process.env': process.env
  }
})
```

And **instead of require**

```
const Cosmic = require('cosmicjs')
```

always use import

```
import Cosmic from "cosmicjs"
```

Besides that, everything works the same as in other API requests, so eg. in my case, I'm API requesting posts from my ***cosmic js Bucket***

```
<script setup lang="ts">

import { ref } from "vue";
import { onMounted } from "vue";
import moment from "moment";
import Cosmic from "cosmicjs"

const api = Cosmic();
const posts = ref([] as any);

const isLoading = ref(false);


const bucket = api.bucket({
  slug: "c27229f0-9018-11ed-b853-65fa50acc7e7",
  read_key: "G71yMNlvizQCtrvVyp9Z1AecQp8a4RTr5dl9uEGi6nst9FNQIW",
});
async function fetchData() {
      isLoading.value = true
      const data = await bucket.objects.find({
        type: 'posts'
      }).props('slug,title,content,metadata') // Limit the API response data by props
      posts.value = data.objects
      isLoading.value = false

      console.log(posts)
    }


onMounted(async () => {
fetchData();    
});

</script>
```

and the iterate through them in my template

```
<template>

    <ul v-if="!isLoading" class="blog-posts-ul" v-for="post in posts" :key="post.slug">
      <div class="posts-card">
        <a
          ><router-link
            :to="/blog/ + post.slug"
            key="post.id"
            class="posts-permalink"
          >
          </router-link
        ></a>
        <img
          v-if="post.metadata.image != null"
          class="post.metadata.hero"
          :src="post.metadata.image.imgix_url"
          :alt="post.title"
        />
        <img v-else src="@/assets/logos/favicon-big.png" />
        <div class="posts-date">
          <p>
            {{ moment(post.date).fromNow() + " " + "ago" }}
          </p>
        </div>

        <div class="posts-text">
          <h1 class="posts-title">{{ post.title }}</h1>

          <p v-html="post.excerpt" class="posts-excerpt"></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </ul>
</template>
```

***As a last sidenote, this works flawlessly compared to `Wordpress` API requests, I was using `Wordpress` for my backend CMS and even with API cache plugin enabled, it took around 800-1100ms to load the posts, now that time shrank to about 30ms for the API request of the text based data, and extra 30-40ms for each image (thumbnails for the posts).***

As a request from a commenter, I'm including some description as to **why Vite needs the change of `vite.config.js`**

Basically, other vue instances **do include by default the `process.env` in their configurations, Vite doesn't cause its generally a slower method for acquiring data** - based on what I read, haven't tested this performance difference myself.

Vite is used instead of simply using Vue CLI, because its supposed to be even a bit faster then Vue CLI.

But, this is a small change.

***"Why it is needed at all? I don't even see in your code above
calling any function named `process`"***

Because it is this `cosmicjs` that is using it. I'm using a service that has a free tier, named Cosmic, and in their documentation it's advised to use their own node_module named `comsicjs` to fetch your data (posts, thumbnails etc etc).

***This node module is what is using process***, so when you are
importing it as I am as you can see above in my code:

```
import Cosmic from "cosmicjs"
```

And this is why you need to change your Vite's configuration file, so it can use `process`.

***TLDR:***
***If you get an error in your Vite project with "process is not defined", that could be because a module you installed is using `process`, so simply add the following code to your `vite.config.ts` or `vite.config.js`***

```
export default defineConfig({
....,
  define: {
    'process.env': process.env
  }
})
```